# Should XCSharedData be checked into Git Repo for Xcode project?

Tags: xcode, git, gitignore

I just made some changes and I see a pending file that has not been added to the repo. The filenames path is */xcshareddata/IDEWorkspaceChecks.plist. Can someone explain the reason for this file and why or why not it needs to be added to the repo?

Answer (score 110, accepted):

The files in `xcshareddata/` should be added to the repo (but not the ones in `xcuserdata/`):

> Xcode 9.3 adds a new IDEWorkspaceChecks.plist file to a workspace's shared data, to store the state of necessary workspace checks. Committing this file to source control will prevent unnecessary rerunning of those checks for each user opening the workspace. (37293167)

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/Introduction.html

---

Regarding **Xcode 9 and newer**, the only line you really need in your .gitignore is:

```
xcuserdata/
```

Nothing else for Xcode 9+. Whatever other lines you have in your .gitignore should be only added for your specific needs, not because you found an obsolete .gitignore sample on the internet. :)

Comment: Theres a github repo thats dedicated to all the git ignore files for all languages, so i usually just add it from there ad customize it to my needs

Comment: @Esko918 Well, you may look at [the author of this commit](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/81d78706fa205764893ab25d83f47a6240abad18/Global/Xcode.gitignore) ;)

Comment: I agree, `xcshareddata` contains target configurations that should probably persist across users of the same project.

Comment: Is there no longer a need for .DS_Store?

Comment: @MurraySagal .DS_Store is not related to Xcode, but to Finder.

Comment: Yes, you're right. But I've seen repos with .DS_Store files and I've seen gitignores that specified .DS_Store. I'm just double checking that in your opinion .DS_Store doesn't need to be added to gitignore.

Comment: @MurraySagal I just consider the question off-topic. Of course .DS_Store should be in your global gitignore when using macOS. Just try `cat ~/.gitignore_global` and it may already be there by default.